# How to format date in DD-MMM-YYYY format eg 29-JAN-2015?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want the date in `DD-MMM-YYYY` format eg 29-JAN-2015.

I have tried with:

```
SELECT TRIM(TO_DATE('29 Jan 2015'
                ,'DD MON YY')) FROM DUAL
```

I got result as: 29-JAN-15

But I am expecting: `29-JAN-2015` in date format not in char format

Comment: TO_DATE(SYSDATE ,'DD MON YYYY'))?

Comment: `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD MON YY')` is complete nonsense. You are implicitly converting a `date` to a string, just to convert it back to  `date` again.

Comment: If you want to format a particular date, use `TO_CHAR()` not `TO_DATE()`. And you should not need `TRIM()`. Simply `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')`.

Comment: I have a table in my project,  in that it has column in char, it has value  as '09 jan 2014'. select  TRIM(TO_DATE('14 Jan 2004'
                    ,'DD MON YY')) from dual. I want in date format as a result not in char.sorry for giving as sysdate in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for answers.
I got the solution. First we need to alter the session as below:

alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY';

then run the query:
SELECT TRIM(TO_DATE('29 Jan 2015'
                    ,'DD MON YYYY'))
FROM DUAL
Now I got result as:29-JAN-2015

Comment: You get that result by pure luck. If you're using this in production code, now you have to make sure everyone's nls_date_format settings are what you expect... and what happens if that breaks something else? Far better to actually understand how the DATE datatype works and how to convert to/from dates from/to strings via to_date and to_char. What Oracle does to your query is to turn it into: `SELECT TRIM(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('29 Jan 2015', 'DD MON YYYY'), '<nls_date_format>')) from dual;` That `TRIM` is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Far, far better to make the conversion explicit in the statement, so that no matter who runs it, it will work as expected. E.g. `SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('29 Jan 2015', 'DD MON YYYY', 'nls_date_language=''american'''),  'DD MON YYYY', 'nls_date_language=''american''') from dual;`

Comment: In my code I alter the session when it required and I altered to old after I fetched the result. More over I want in date format not in char format as u suggested, read question once again. Nothing is pure luck. I got this solution by googling

Comment: Any time you are displaying something that is in date format, your are actually converting it back into a string (especially when you're throwing it into a function that works only with strings!). So yes, that extra to_char is necessary, assuming you are wanting to see the date displayed in a particular format. Relying on changing the nls_date_format parameter is, in my opinion, nothing short of madness. It's something you would do on an ad-hoc basis, not as part of proper production code. Why bother with two separate commands when you can do it in one?

Comment: What exactly is it you're wanting to do with the date once you've got it in the right format? If it's to update another column that's a DATE (or store it in a DATE variable or something) then worrying about how the string is formatted is irrelevant, since it's already a date.

Comment: I am sending the date to excel file not to any table, this is my requirement. so your suggestion doesn't work here

Comment: in which case, my solution is *perfect* for what you need: `SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(your_date_as_string_column, 'DD MON YYYY', 'nls_date_language=''american'''), 'DD MON YYYY', 'nls_date_language=''american''') from your_table;` You can run that regardless of what your nls_date_format settings are.  (This is assuming you're going to export manually into the spreadsheet. If it's programatically, then leave the date as a date, but let whatever is doing the export into excel handle the display of the date.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69831/discussion-between-sravanth-kothuri-and-boneist).

Comment: I can't access that. DATE is an internal Oracle datatype. It's not human readable. In order for humans to read something stored as a DATE, Oracle **must** convert it into a string (TO_CHAR). Similarly, when we want to pass a specific date into a DATE field/variable, we must pass in a string and convert it into something Oracle recognises as a DATE (TO_DATE). If you request Oracle to display a DATE without explicitly doing a TO_CHAR, you are then relying on Oracle implicitly converting the DATE into a string. It does this by doing TO_CHAR behind the scenes, using whatever the nls_date_format...

Comment: ...is set to. I.e. if you say `select sysdate from dual;` Oracle converts that to `select to_char(sysdate, '<nls_date_format>') from dual;` behind the scenes. It has to; there is no other way of displaying the DATE. So, you have two options - you can rely on whatever the nls_date_format is set to (and amend as appropriate), but now anyone else who runs that query must do the same, or you can explicitly set the format directly in your query. Your choice, but what happens if you forget to set the nls_date_format one time? Better to have the query define how the results are returned.

Answer (score 9):

Im assuming Oracle DB:

```
select to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
```

Returns

```
29-Jan-2015
```

Comment: I am expecting in date format. select TRIM(TO_DATE('14 Jan 2004' ,'DD MON YY')) from dual . I am expecting output as 14-jan-2014 as date format not in char

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is take the string '29 Jan 2015' and make it a date using the format 'DD MON YY'. This should fail of course for '2015' not matching 'yy', but Oracle is lenient here.

Then you use TRIM on the date. But TRIM is for strings. What happens is that you get shown '29 Jan 15'. I am getting shown '29.01.15' instead of the usual '29.01.2015'. However the behavior: Don't use TRIM on dates, its behavior is nowhere specified as far as I am aware. Use TO_CHAR to format a date in output.

If you only select a date without TO_CHAR you get the date shown in some standard format, which can be '29 Jan 2015' or '29 Jan 15' or '29.01.2015' or '01/29/2015' depending on the app you are using and possibly some setting therin.

For completeness sake:

TO_DATE takes a string ('29 Jan 2015' in your case) and converts it to a date. If the string contains names, make sure that you specify the appropriate language setting:

```
TO_DATE('29 Jan 2015', 'dd mon yyyy', ''NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
```

To get a formatted string from a date, use TO_CHAR:

```
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'dd MON yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
```

Usually you don't do that, however. You select a date as is and have your app (written in PHP, Java or whatever) care about how to display it appropriately to the user's computer's settings.

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server the query

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 106) as [Converted Date]
```

returns:

```
29 Jan 2015
```

Comment: It is not exactly what the original question was about (` ` instead of `-`), but it might be useful to have a link where the number `106` get explained in case someone looks for alternatives. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Manu is correct. Oracle publish a full list of date format specifiers.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA

Comment: This is not an answer. Plus manu is *not* correct, because `to_date()` on a `date` makes no sense. Additionally: link only answers are frowned upon here

Comment: Apologies - meant rbm with the to_char.

Answer (score -3):

Use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)`

See detailed explanation here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: That is invalid for Oracle. (Plus you should avoid w3schools it's full of errors)

Comment: This is SQL Server syntax rather than Oracle

Answer (score -4):

Can you try:

```
SELECT TRIM(TO_DATE(SYSDATE ,'DD MON YYYY')) FROM DUAL
```

`YY` will only show 2 ciphers, instead of `YYYY` that will show 4.

Comment: `TO_DATE(SYSDATE ,'DD MON YYYY')` is nonsense

Comment: For your query, result will come as 29-JAN-15 not 29-JAN-2015. i have wrong query in question, this is correct select TRIM(TO_DATE('14 Jan 2004' ,'DD MON YYYY')) from dual. I am not as 14-jan-2004